Ignition Web Dev Module
I'm trying to make a call to ignition web dev module over https. The problem is that ignition web dev module serves with http so I'm getting mixed content error. Is it somehow possible to make ignition web dev module serve over https?

"web dev module serves with http" I don't believe this is entirely correct. Can you show the stack trace of the fault?
